# Parsing out a table from a web page?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am very new to coding and I am trying to make a console app that will show the current premier league table(football).

Using this URL "https://www.premierleague.com/matchweek/3277/table".

I am using the HTML agility pack. I have tried this:

```
var url = "https://www.premierleague.com/matchweek/3277/table";
        var HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
        var TableList = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("tbody")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", " ")
        .Equals("standingEntriesContainer")).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't word this very well. I was wondering how to display the table from the url in console and get the valuable information I want out of the HTML document. My current solution doesn't seem to parse out the information I want.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question or describe your problem.

Comment: Sorry, first question I hope my edit clears up what I am having a problem with.

Comment: Your edit isn't much better.  What information do you want?  What table are you expecting?  We can't read your mind.

Comment: The PL table displayed in the URL. Showing the position of the teams, Pts and GD+ etc. In the same format/ order as the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty close. Just a few more extra steps.
For example:

```
        var table = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("tbody")
        .FirstOrDefault(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", " ")
        .Equals("standingEntriesContainer") && node.ChildNodes.Count > 0);

        foreach (var tr in table.ChildNodes)
        {
            Console.Write(tr.ChildNodes[0].Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault().InnerText);
            Console.Write(tr.ChildNodes[1].Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().InnerText);
            Console.Write(tr.ChildNodes[2].InnerText);
            Console.Write(tr.ChildNodes[3].InnerText);
            Console.Write(tr.ChildNodes[4].InnerText);
        }
```

Something like this would work and you can reformat your table data as you want. I just quickly created it.